# Orthogonal coordinate frame

Tags: differential-geometry

On a Riemannian manifold  $(M,g)$, there always exists local orthonormal frame $\{E_i\}$ with respect to the metric $g$. But there does not necessarily exist orthonormal coordinate frame $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \}$ in a small neighborhood around a point $p$, where $\{x^i:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ } are coordinate maps.

My question is the follow:
 instead of local orthonormal coordinate frame, is it possible to find local orthogonal coordinate frame?  i.e. with respect to some coordinate system, the metric g can be written locally as $$g= g_{ii} {dx^{i}}dx^i$$

For surface, I know this is true because of something stronger, the existence of isothermal coordinate. I wonder whether this is possible for higher dimension.

Comment: Isn't this just a rescaling? It seems to me if you could do this, you could just multiply by some diagonal matrix which would make it orthonormal in that region.

Comment: There are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ so that $\partial/\partial x^i$ are orthonormal (or orthogonal of any fixed lengths) if and only if the manifold is flat (zero sectional curvature) and hence locally isometric to $\Bbb R^n$.